# AWS API Gateway won't open up

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created a "hello world" lambda function and then deployed it to an end-point using AWS's **API Gateway**:

[image: config settings]

All very much basic settings but I was sure to change the security to "open" and while i was told that it could take up for 15 minutes for the domain to resolve I found that even after 30 I was getting the following response from the "open" end-point:

```
 {"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Am I missing something obvious? Shouldn't this have been available with what I did?

---

Note, it was pointed out that this image is of a PUT not a GET. I tried both and both came back errors. Just to check I've run GET and PUT through **Postman** and get a similar but not identical response:

[image: PUT]

and then GET ...

[image: GET]

When I test the lambda function in the console it runs successfully but running it in the API Gateway it gives me a different articulation of the same error:

> Tue Sep 29 20:57:43 UTC 2015 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function

and yet I used the default permissions that the console suggested. The lambda function itself is very basic and can be found here: [code](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/b47f31f893bb621a63ef)

Comment: This is the generic response for "you did something wrong". Show how you're sending your request to the API.

Comment: They give a URL link in the AWS console (it's just a parameterless GET); I just clicked on it. What additional info should I include?

Comment: Well, there is your problem right there. When you click the URL you're doing a GET, but your screenshot shows the method is PUT. A PUT method won't answer GET requests.

Comment: Actually is see the picture I posted was a PUT but that was attempt two ... Same outcome with a GET

Comment: I've updated the question to include both GET and PUT responses (which are the same).

Comment: Missing authentication token error is given when calling an invalid URL. From the information you have given, I would guess the correct URL is whatever.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloColdWorld2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue with a deployed API that was being hit frequently around midday the requests would stop working and fail with { Missing Authentication Token }

My issue was not the URL or a stage that was not deployed but I do know AWS throws that error for both of those reasons.

However I found a command to invalidate the cache of apigateway because in my case I was using a custom domain attached to cloudfront.

```
aws apigateway flush-stage-cache --rest-api-id 97y41psdkg --stage-name dev
```

After running this I stopped getting the { Missing Authentication Token }

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exact some problem today. Whatever I did didn't work but finally figured out. turns out in order for the changes to take effect, you need to Deploy API.

So first go to **Resources** and click on **Deploy API** button. It will ask for a deployment stage. Once deployed I could call my API without any issues.

I know it's been a while since you posted the question, but thought it might come in handy for other people as well.

Comment: Thanks @volkan, sounds like your situation was a bit different from mine but sadly I left this question out there and forgot to update my answer (which of course I've now forgotten). I think mine was down to needing proxy through the SNS ARN topic in the right fashion so your answer might be more broadly applicable. :)

Comment: Here's where I ended up ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213464/aws-api-gateway-communicating-to-sns?noredirect=1#comment58441715_34213464

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "AWS Signature" under the Authorization tab in Postman. See this AWS guide on what to enter into those fields:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use your resource name end of your api URL.

https://***********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Stag/number

Here number is my resource name