# AWS API-Gateway communicating to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

I am building an API which will be serviced by Lambda functions but I need these to be asynchronous so rather than connecting the API-Gateway directly to the Lambda function I'm using the "AWS Service Proxy" to *publish* SNS messages and then have the Lambda function subscribe to the relevant SNS topic so it receives delivery of the requests. Here's a picture which illustrates the flow:

[image]

I have tested both the Lambda function in isolation as well pub/sub messaging between SNS and Lambda but I am struggling with the API-Gateway to SNS handoff. Documentation is quite light but what I am assuming right now is that the following attributes must be sent in the POST request:

1. **Action**: the API-Gateway offers to set this in the UI and I have put in the **Publish** action which is the appropriate SNS action
2. **Message**: the body of the POST message should be a JSON document. It would be passed by the web client and proxied through the gateway to SNS.
3. **TopicArn**: indicates the SNS topic that we're publishing to. In my design this would be a static value/endpoint so I'd prefer that the web-client not have to pass this too but if it were easier to do this that would be fine too.

I have tried lots of things but am just stuck. Would love to find a good code example somewhere but any help at all would be appreciated.

---

Wanted to add a little more context on my current attempt:

I have tried publishing my API and using Postman to try and get a valid response. Here's the postman screens(one for header vars, one for JSON body):

[image: header variables]
[image: json body]

This results in the following error message:

```
{
   "Error": {
     "Code": "InvalidParameter",
     "Message": "Invalid parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required parameter",
     "Type": "Sender"
  },
  "RequestId": "b33b7700-e8a3-58f7-8ebe-39e4e62b02d0"
}
```

the error seems to indicate that the **TopicArn** parameter is not being sent to SNS but I have included the following in API-Gateway:

[image]

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?  I am running into similar problems with the exact same architecture.  Before I post a separate question detailing my issues I figured I'd see if you were able to get this working.

Comment: Uh oh. I had posted an answer but it didn't go through. I'll try to get to this tomorrow.

Comment: Have you managed to get this running using POST requests? The only way I managed to do it is by setting TopicArn and Message as query string parameters (like the answer below propose), because request body was always ignored even though I set POST method. I need what's in the request body though and it seems there's no way I can copy it as a query string parameter.

Comment: Yes it appears you can _not_ use the request body at this time. This will get fixed at some point but no dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did eventually get this to work after working with AWS support. Here's my solution:

- First of all even though you're sending a `POST` you will *not* be able to send a JSON message in the body of the message as you might expect
- Instead you must URL Encode the JSON and pass it as query parameter
- Also remember that the JSON you send should start with a root object of `default` which in SNS-world means the "default channel"
- Then, eventually Lambda picks up the SNS event you must also abstract away a lot of the noise to get at your JSON message. For this I created the following function that I use within my Lambda function:

```js
/**
 * When this is run in AWS it is run "through" a SNS
 * event wconfig.ich adds a lot of clutter to the event data,
 * this tests for SNS data and normalizes when necessary
 */
function abstractSNS(e) {
  if (e.Records) {
    return JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(e.Records[0].Sns.Message)).default;
  } else {
    return e;
  }
}

/**
 * HANDLER
 * This is the entry point for the lambda function
 */
exports.handler = function handler(event, context) {
  parent.event = abstractSNS(event);
```

Comment: Hello, can you give some details of your solution like what part you have to change/what part differ from normal setup?? I am having this problem for last 2 days and stuck. Problem is i am not clear with the solution you gave above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes not sure what else to add ... the "handler" function gives you a `event` object but if you're using SNS to fire the event you'll get the full SNS event. For me the SNS details are not very useful except for what is in the `e.Records[0].Sns.Message` so the above function unwraps the part I care about.

Comment: Note that now API Gateway provides a direct way to call Lambda _and_ invoke it asynchronously so you don't **need** to use SNS in some cases.

Comment: my problem is describe here in details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229941/using-api-gateway-to-publish-sns-topics-multiple-lambda-function-with-api-gate

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes what you're trying to do is definitely achievable and a good use-case for SNS. Where in the chain are things breaking down? Is API-Gateway firing the SNS message (if you have any doubts you can just subscribe to the SNS topic via email)? If it is, do your lambda functions execute? I would need more insight into where in the chain things aren't working for you.

Comment: @ken, there are still some use cases that messages should be published to SNS from API Gateway instead of invoking Lambda. One is because of Lambda cold start issue and my app needs to publish data in real time.

Answer (score 13):

I'm from the Api Gateway team.

I believe there are a few formats for the HTTP request to the Publish API, but here's the one I used first:

AWS Region us-west-2

AWS Service sns

AWS Subdomain

HTTP method POST

Action Publish

== query strings ==

Subject 'foo'
Message 'bar'
TopicArn 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxx:test-api'

This worked for me to publish a message.

Let me know if you have further troubles.

Jack

Comment: How do i map the request body and the params sent in the request to the Subject, Message, and TopicArn for SNS?

Comment: He mentioned in a bullet point that the message should be in POST. I don't understand why recommended AWS documentation is to encode a message in a query string.

Answer (score 13):

If anybody is still looking for a solution to the original problem, proxying a JSON request body to an SNS topic via API gateway alone, it's possible.

Create the gateway as Ken describes above. Then simply proxy the body to the [Integration Request's query parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrNaD.png). You can also hard code Subject, TopicArn, etc here, or map those from the request's body using a [JsonPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-request-parameters).

For example:

```
{
   //body
   "topic": "arn:aws:sns:1234567:topic"
}
```

Could be mapped to a header as:

```
method.request.body.topic
```

Comment: Came to say the same thing. This really ought to be the accepted answer.

Comment: I think the screenshot is wrong though. It should just be `stageVariables.topicArn`, not `'$stageVariables.TopicArn'`.

Comment: This is what works. Thanks a ton. Spent 3 days to figure out what on earth is wrong !!

Comment: How can you hardcode the subject and topicarn? I do not want the caller to specify them. Thanks

Comment: Ok, solved. You just pass it in the integration request mappings with ticks `'your-topic-arn'`

Answer (score 4):

You could use API Gateway to invoke your Lambda function asynchronously by configuring it as an AWS service proxy. The configuration is basically the same you see in [this GitHub sample](https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store/blob/master/src/main/resources/swagger.yaml#L38), with the exception that the uri for the Lambda invocation changes to [/invoke-async/](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_InvokeAsync.html) instead of just /invoke/

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your example. Where does this YAML go? Can API-Gateway import Swagger definitions?

Comment: Also note that invoke-async is deprecated ... they recommend using invoke instead (I believe there is a parameter to set it to async though)

Comment: Is it possible to export a Swagger YAML definition for an API I setup using the UI? Would be nice to see it in YAML form rather than just the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a step by step guide for people who still couldn't figure it out after looking through the above answers. The variable names are case sensitive so make sure you are exact.

1. Open the Post Method
   a. Select **Method Request**
   b. Change Request Validator to `Validate body, query string parameters, and headers`
   c. Expand URL Query String Parameters
   d. Add the following two query string parameters
   Name: `TopicArn` ----> Select Required
   Name: `Message` -----> Select Required
2. Return to the Post Method and open **Integration Request**
   a. Expand URL Query String Parameters
   b. Add the following two query string parameters
   Name: `TopicArn`     Mapped from: `method.request.querystring.TopicArn`
   Name: `Message`      Mapped from: `method.request.querystring.Message`
3. When testing, alter the below command to match your SNS ARN and put it in Query Strings.
   `TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:1234567890:SNSName&Message="Hello from API Gateway"`

Sources/Further Information:
[API Gateway Proxy Integration Service Guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-integrate-service/)
[SNS Publish Method Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am just speculating (haven't tried this myself), but I think you are not sending the message correctly...

Based on AWS's documentation here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html), you need to POST the message in what seems to be the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding like this:

```
POST http://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1
...
Action=Publish
&Message=%7B%22default%22%3A%22This+is+the+default+Message%22%2C%22APNS_SANDBOX%22%3A%22%7B+%5C%22aps%5C%22+%3A+%7B+%5C%22alert%5C%22+%3A+%5C%22You+have+got+email.%5C%22%2C+%5C%22badge%5C%22+%3A+9%2C%5C%22sound%5C%22+%3A%5C%22default%5C%22%7D%7D%22%7D
&TargetArn=arn%3Aaws%3Asns%3Aus-west-2%3A803981987763%3Aendpoint%2FAPNS_SANDBOX%2Fpushapp%2F98e9ced9-f136-3893-9d60-776547eafebb
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
&SignatureVersion=2
&Version=2010-03-31
&Signature=vmqc4XRupKAxsDAdN4j4Ayw5LQljXMps3kss4bkDfCk%3D
&Timestamp=2013-07-18T22%3A44%3A09.452Z
&MessageStructure=json
```

That is, the message body looks the way a browser would encode form data. Your message can be JSON formatted, but still needs to be encoded as if it was a form field (an awkward analogy :)).

Also, based on the common parameters documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/CommonParameters.html), you have a number of additional required fields (the usual access key, signature and so on).

You have not specified what language you are writing your API Gateway in - there might be an AWS SDK for it that you can use, instead of trying to manually compose the REST requests).

Comment: WRT to language, the Lambda functions at the end of this flow are Node JS, the calling web client is a JS SPA (EmberJS). In between -- where the message transformation is taking place -- is all just API Gateway configuration.

Comment: The example message you've given does look like its urlencoded, the example above it seemed to suggest that you could pass in JSON into the body message (at least that's how I read it).

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that signing and passing along the Access Key is all handled by the API-Gateway as that would break the "configuration only" approach they seem to be promoting (and the UI does ask for execution arn)

Comment: Apologies - I am completely off in my answer. I though the API Gateway is a component you wrote (did not realize AWS has a product called this way :).

Comment: Thanks anyway, I need all the help I can get. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like:

WebApp --> Gateway --> Lambda ( Use Boto3 to publish in  SNS ) --> SNS -->Lambda

I think, things will be simpler.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Okay  so We connect Gateway to Lambda. as per doc:  https://cloudonaut.io/create-a-serverless-restful-api-with-api-gateway-cloudformation-lambda-and-dynamodb/ and then use http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish .....to connect lambda to SNS

Comment: Let me know if this helps or I will post with images,,Only thing is this will use Python

Answer (score 1):

Also remember parameters are case sensitive; I also received the OP's error: `"Message": "Invalid parameter: TopicArn or TargetArn Reason: no value for required parameter"`

The only problem was case sensitivity of the parameters (specifically it should be: "TopicArn" and "Message").  These are set in the Method Execution | POST - Integration Request section, in the "Name" field.

The capitalization of the "Mapped from" is important that it matches the params being sent through from the Method Request configuration, but what is sent on to SNS is the "Name" field of "Integration Request", and that is what I had wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's looking for an example of this in 2023 using Terraform with the OpenAPI configuration, here's what I used

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "MyApi" {
  name = "${var.name}-${var.environment}"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "AWS" : aws_iam_role.api-gateway-access-role.arn
        },
        "Action" : "execute-api:Invoke",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:*/*/*/*"
        "Condition" : {
          "StringEquals" : {
            "aws:SourceVpc" : data.terraform_remote_state.vpc.outputs.vpc_id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
  body = jsonencode({
    "openapi" : "3.0.1",
    "info" : {
      "title" : "MyApi",
      "version" : "0.1.0"
    },
    "paths" : {
      "/my-in-principle" : {
        "post" : {
          "x-amazon-apigateway-auth" : {
            "type" : "AWS_IAM"
          },
          "x-amazon-apigateway-integration" : {
            "uri" : "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.aws_region}:sns:path/${aws_sns_topic.my-request.arn}?Action=Publish&TopicArn=${aws_sns_topic.my-request.arn}",
            "passthroughBehavior" : "when_no_templates",
            "credentials" : aws_iam_role.sns-access-role.arn,
            "httpMethod" : "POST",
            "type" : "aws",
            "requestTemplates" : {
              "application/json" : "{\"Message\": $input.json('$')}"
            },
            "requestParameters" : {
              "integration.request.querystring.Message" : "method.request.body"
            }
            "responses" : {
              "400" : {
                "statusCode" : "400",
                "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
                "responseTemplates" : {
                  "application/json" : "$input.json('$')"
                },
              },
              "500" : {
                "statusCode" : "500",
                "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
                "responseTemplates" : {
                  "application/json" : "$input.json('$')"
                },
              },
              "200" : {
                "statusCode" : "200",
                "contentHandling" : "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
                "responseTemplates" : {
                  "application/json" : "$input.json('$')"
                },
              }
            }
          },
          "responses" : {
            "200" : {
              "description" : "Successful Response"
            },
            "400" : {
              "description" : "Bad Request"
            },
            "500" : {
              "description" : "Internal Server Error"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  endpoint_configuration {
    types            = ["PRIVATE"]
    vpc_endpoint_ids = [data.aws_vpc_endpoint.execute-api.id]
  }
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "my-request-topic-policy" {
  arn = aws_sns_topic.my-request.arn
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Id      = "default",
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid    = "AllowAPIGatewayToPublish",
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action   = "sns:Publish",
        Resource = aws_sns_topic.my-request.arn,
        Condition = {
          ArnEquals = {
            "aws:SourceArn" = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.id}/*/*/*"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "sns-access-role" {
  name = "sns-access-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17",
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Principal = {
          Service = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
        },
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
  inline_policy {
    name = "sns-publish-policy"
    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17",
      Statement = [
        {
          Effect = "Allow",
          Action = [
            "sns:Publish"
          ],
          Resource = [
            aws_sns_topic.my-request.arn
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "MyMethodSettings" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.id
  stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.MyApiStage.stage_name
  method_path = "*/*"

  settings {
    throttling_rate_limit  = "5"
    throttling_burst_limit = "20"
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "MyDeployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.body,
      aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.policy
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "MyApiStage" {
  rest_api_id          = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.id
  stage_name           = "v1"
  deployment_id        = aws_api_gateway_deployment.MyDeployment.id
  xray_tracing_enabled = true
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "MyLambdaInvokePermission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.Async-Lambda.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # More: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html
  source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.MyApi.id}/*/*/*"
}
```