# One endpoint, multiple lambdas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We receive large amount of data 24hour by endpoint and after the endpoint, there is a lambda function doing it's job the send data to s3. But we want other lambda that also can get the payload and doing something with this data. How to do that?

Or if I want to achieve similar result, what is the circumvent?

Currently, we are doing some stupid method, inside one lambda call other lambda to send lambda to that lambda...

Answer (score 2):

Your current method of "one Lambda function calling another Lambda function" is fine, but here's an alternative:

- **API Gateway** invokes the **AWS Lambda function**
- That Lambda function sends a message to an **Amazon SNS Topic**
- Lambda function exits

Then, **create a separate Lambda function for each process** you want to perform on the message and subscribe that Lambda function to the SNS Topic.

**Result:**

- First Lambda function causes a **'fan out'** to the other Lambda functions
- All the Lambda functions can **process the messages in parallel**
- Add/remove Lambda functions by simply controlling the **subscriptions** on the SNS Topic

Comment: Thanks. Just get to know that AWS support one API gateway with multiple lambda, I'm configuring the CF to see if it works.

Comment: Well, that certainly does sound easier. Thanks for the tip! [[AWS] How to use one API Gateway to invoke multiple Lambda functions | One Hardware Engineer](https://onehwengineer.com/aws-api-gateway-invoke-lambda/)

Comment: Or just have API gateway to directly produces messages to SNS (apparently [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229941/using-api-gateway-to-publish-sns-topics-multiple-lambda-function-with-api-gate)) and then all interested lambdas could subscribe? But the data limit of SNS message is 256 KB, and also the limit on event payload of lambda is 256 KB. So not sure what does OP mean by "lambda send the data to S3", is it just the payload that lambda sends to S3? It depends.