# API Gateway stage variable always null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use stage variables, but I always get this error:

```
{
  "logref": "some_uid",
  "message": "Invalid stage variable value: null.  Please use values with alphanumeric characters and the symbols ' ', -', '.', '_', ':', '/', '?', '&', '=', and ','."
}
```

My goal is to call SNS from API gateway **without the need from the caller to specify the `TopicArn` and the `Message` in the query string**.

So in the **Integration Request** I am mapping the query string `TopicArn` to `stageVariables.TopicArn` (I have tried `'$stageVariables.TopicArn'` as well).

And then in the Stage variables section in AWS console I input the Name `TopicArn` and the Value `arn:aws:sns:my_region:my_account_id:test-topic`

After I deployed my API I test it from the AWS console and I get this error:

```
{
  "logref": "some_uid",
  "message": "Invalid stage variable value: null.  Please use values with alphanumeric characters and the symbols ' ', -', '.', '_', ':', '/', '?', '&', '=', and ','."
}
```

What am I doing wrong, it his achievable?

Comment: Same for me. Followed the approach as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846352/1002217 but it looks like it can't find the stage variable... if i try to use the ARN directly as a value in query param it won't be accepted.

Comment: just saw your solution as a comment to the other post. Very nice, worked for me as well. Maybe you should also provide it here as well for others.

Comment: @mikaint which answer, the one for static values? Let me know so I will add it here, thanks