# How to parse input from frontend to AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS and I am trying to build a web application where every time I type in my name and address and click the submit button, I want this information to be sent to SNS to notify a device that a new entry has been received along with the inputs given. I am wondering if I should first create a lambda function to get my name and address before triggering the SNS. I am still not clear what would be a good workflow here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interact with Amazon SNS from a web app, you do not need to write a lot of Lambda functions to interact with the service. Instead, you can directly invoke the SNS Service by using the Amazon SNS API.

For example, assume you want to write a Web app using Java. To solve this use case, you can write the Web App using Spring BOOT and then use the SNS Java API to invoke SNS Service Operations, as discussed in this development article.

[Creating a Publish/Subscription Spring Boot Application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_sns_sample_app)

Likewise, if you are using another programming language, you can use that given API to build the web app and invoke SNS operations.

Comment: thank you. that is my aim. I am using React for the front end and my idea is to pass the inputs sent from the frontend into an api gateway which will then send the messages to SNS.

Comment: Another option you have is to use the AWS SDK for Javascript to invoke AWS Services directly. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html

Comment: i am using aws-cdk and my idea is similar to what is being asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213464/aws-api-gateway-communicating-to-sns but it seems like it still needs to go through a lambda function